# TextView /EditText MaxLength should not consider dot or sign as a digit/character

Tags: android

In my android Calculator app Code i have a TextView & an EditText. I have used android:maxLength="10" to limit input upto 10 digits for both views. I also want decimal point(dot) & sign(-) to be entered by user & the user is able to do that. But when the user types a dot or sign, actual digit input remains upto 9 digits only.

The question is how can i exclude dot & sign from being counted as character/digit & hence user can input 10 digits with a dot & sign as well???
Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the restrict the input of certain characters by using the `setFilter()` method of `EditText`, along with an `InputFilter`. The example code below provides an example of how to apply an `InputFilter` to a specified `EditText`:

```
private EditText edInputField;
private String sRestrictedCharacters = ".-";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edInputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edInputField);
    edInputField.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { ipCharacterFilter });
}

private InputFilter ipCharacterFilter = new InputFilter()
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence ipCharacterFilter(CharSequence restrChars, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (restrChars != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + restrChars)))
        {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

The example code above creates an `InputFilter` based on the excluded characters in the `String` `sRestrictedCharacters`, and then applies this filter to the `EditText` using the `setFilters()` method. If you wish to filter additional characters beyond just `.` & `-`, you need only append said characters to `sRestrictedCharacters`.

**EDIT**

You may also use `InputFilter` to allow you to dynamically increase the number of allowed characters in your `EditText`. Consider the example below...

When you create your `EditText` you can create a filter to limit the number of characters that the user may enter, shown below:

```
int maxEditTextChars = 10;
InputFilter[] lengthFilter = new InputFilter[1];
lengthFilter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxEditTextChars);
edInputField.setFilters(lengthFilter);
```

Then, when you detect that an invalid character has been entered, you simply increment the maximum number of allowed characters and reapply the filter:

```
maxEditTextChars += 1;
lengthFilter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxEditTextChars);
edInputField.setFilters(lengthFilter);
```

Comment: Hi Willis! As per your answer I am able to stop the user from entering specific characters... what i am looking for' will be something like: ' if(ed.contains(".") && ed.contains("-"){ //increase the ed.length()+1}'. but i am not able to get this properly to how to write the code. eg:" maxLenth="10". edittext has digits"1234567890" when dot is present, edittext has digits"12345.6789". dot has consumed one digits place. wht i am looking for is "12345.67890" i.e when dot is present maxlength is increased to 11 characters/digits.